# How to store a relationship between a file and a model in Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel-5

I have the below controller. I need to save the Document Model with the Employee_id relationship. I have the relationship set correctly but I a, having SQL error where it says employee_id cannot be null, foreign key violation.

So I think I have to find a way for the controller to recognise the currently loaded id for the employee profile view then save the document model. The upload works fine. It's writing to the DB part that I need help.  Code here....

```
public function createdocument(Request $request, Employee $id)
{


    $file = $request->file('file');
    $allowedFileTypes = config('app.allowedFileTypes');
    $maxFileSize = config('app.maxFileSize');
    $rules = [
        'file' => 'required|mimes:'.$allowedFileTypes.'|max:'.$maxFileSize
    ];
    $this->validate($request, $rules);


    $time = time();  
    $filename = ($time.'_'.($file->getClientOriginalName())); // Prepend the filename 
     $destinationPath = config('app.fileDestinationPath').'/'.$filename;
        $uploaded = Storage::put($destinationPath, file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));
        if($uploaded){

            $employee = Employee::find($id); 

            EmpDocuments::create([
                'employee_id' => $employee,
                'name' => $filename
            ]);
        }    
        return redirect('employees');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you print_r($employee), it should return object, that's why its giving null exception.

You have to get ID of employee:

```
EmpDocuments::create([
    'employee_id' => $employee->id,
    'name' => $filename
]);
```

Also, your saying that your sending $id of employee to model, but instead, it expects Employee object. Not id.

So you have to change

```
createdocument(Request $request, Employee $id)
```

to

```
createdocument(Request $request, $id)
```

Comment: If I change to as above I start to get a Missing argument 2 for DocumentsController::createdocument() @plexcell

Comment: Remove "Employee $id" from constructor and send employee id with request. Get id from POST and it should work.